# Linq find all with certain type

Tags: c#, linq

Is there a way to find in a List all items of a certain type with a Linq/Lambda expression?

Update: Because of the answers, I realize the question wasn't specific enough. I need a new List with only the items of a specific type. In my case, the class hasn't got any subclasses, so no need to take inheritance into account.

Comment: Could you state whether or not you'd like to disregard inheritance? E.g. if you wanted all Object types, would you want just Object types or include all subclasses of Object. Some of the answers will do the first, others the second.

Comment: I see, in my case the class hasn't got any subclasses.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

Use `OfType<T>` like so:

```
foreach (var bar in MyList.OfType<Foo>()) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Using the IEnumerable<T> extension method OfType<T> is the microsoft recommended way of doing this.

Answer (score 39):

Will this do?

```
list.Where(t => t is MyType);
```

Comment: But you still have to cast the result, if you use OfType the result is also casted.

Comment: Perfect! I have a situation where two classes inherit the same Abstract class but different interfaces. The OfType<> method cast the list whereas this method of using "is" did exactly what I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could use ...

```
        List<object> list = new List<object>();
        list.Add("string");
        list.Add(9);

        var allOfOneType = list.Where(i => i.GetType().Equals(typeof(string)));
```

Comment: Yeah ... Dave Markles answer is better -- maybe :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (if using Linq to objects - it won't work with Linq to entities):

```
var specificListOfTypes = from item in list
                            where item.GetType() == typeof(int)
                            select item;
```

Comment: You can't use GetType(). It throw the following error: "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Type GetType()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

Comment: ok, so you can't use GetType() in LINQ to Entities, but LINQ to objects does work

Answer (score -4):

You can use the GetType() method and compare with the specified type.

For instance , I select all values of the string type from the list below:

```
   var myList = new List<object>();

        myList.Add(5);

        myList.Add("My life");

        var result = from obj in myList
                     where obj.GetType() == typeof(string)
                     select obj;
```

Comment: This throws an error, "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Type GetType()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."