# See if a list contains a specific type

Tags: c#

Please see the class structures below:

```
public interface ISport { ... }

public class Football: ISport { … }

public class Running : ISport { … }
```

and the client code below:

```
List<ISport> sports = new List<ISport>();
sports.Add(new Football());
sports.Add(new Running());

bool containsFootball = sports.Contains(typeof(Running));
```

The error I get is:

> "Cannot convert from system.type to ISport".

How to resolve?

Comment: Maybe this?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4452590/c-sharp-get-the-item-type-for-a-generic-list

Comment: `sports` contains *objects*, not types.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linq find all with certain type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3236445/linq-find-all-with-certain-type)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use `OfType<T>()` such as `var contains = sports.OfType<Running>().Any()`

Answer (score 4):

Just use `Any` and compare the type:

```
bool containsRunning = sports.Any(sport => sport is Running);
```