# Codition in list with GetType

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core

I would like to add a condition here to gets only types != Int.

```
List<IMyLayouts> list = query.GetType().
GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public).
Select(l => (IMyLayouts)l.GetValue(query, null)).ToList();
```

but

```
.Where(l => (IMyLayouts)l.GetTYpe() != typeof(int)
```

it does not work, I search the internet about it but I can't find anything :|

Comment: Are you sure all of the types in your last `.Where` statement can be cast to `IMyLayouts`?  Why do this casting when trying to type check vs `int`?

Comment: 1) `.` has precedence over cast, so you are casting `l.GetTYpe()` (what is `GetTYpe`?) to `IMyLayouts` - does `GetTYpe` return something that will cast? 2) You are comparing `IMyLayouts` to `typeof(int)` but that can never match - `IMyLayouts` is not a `Type` object 3) your first query query casts `GetValue` of all public properties to `IMyLayouts` but you apparently know some are `int` so that is incorrect as well.

Comment: In IMyLayouts I have public properties of different types e.g. LayoutEmployee, LayoutEmployer etc. I would like to return all types except int

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linq find all with certain type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3236445/linq-find-all-with-certain-type)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what is your goal but if you want to just find the integer types in a list you can use [oftype](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_OfType__1_System_Collections_IEnumerable_) method.

For example you can do like below:

```
var intList = from s in mylist.OfType<int>()  
select s;  
foreach (var item in intList)  
{  
   Console.WriteLine(item);  
}
```

it works with complex objects too. We assume *Customer* is a class or interface. Than you can do like below:

```
var customerList = from s in mylist.OfType<Customer>()  
select s;  
foreach (var customer in customerList)  
{  
   Console.WriteLine(customer.Name);  
 }
```

**UPDATE**

**For finding all defined types in a class  except integer ones you can do like below**  :

```
IEnumerable<System.Reflection.PropertyInfo> types = typeof(MyClass).GetProperties().Where(p => p.PropertyType != 
typeof(int));
```

Comment: I would like to return all types except int

Comment: @jrJerry Have a look the code samples I added. This code finds all types that defined in a class except integer ones.

Comment: How do you save it to the list<IMyLayouts>?

Comment: @jrJerry what do you mean ? after you run the code I gave you will have a list of PropertyInfo that contains information about your properties. you can save them how you want. What is IMyLayouts ?

Comment: My mistake, forgive me @nzrytmn. It works, Thank you for your help.